# Create dump file using pg_dump tool

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, port, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to create a dump file using the pg_dump tool as specified [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import), but I keep getting this result:

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser app_db > app_db.dump
  Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'm using OSX Lion for a rally sort time, and still don't know how can I open or close ports, so, If that's the issue, please tell me how can I open it, if the problem is other thing, please tell me what it is (and how to solve it)

Thanks

Comment: Apparently your Postgres server is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have postgresql installed and running